# query for fetching only one integer value using php

Tags: php, mysql

hey i just want a query which will be printing only the result of count query . put in the else part

```
          <?php


            $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
            $db = mysql_select_db('quiz', $con) or die(mysql_error());
            $q="count(*) from question where ans=uanswer";
            $rq=mysql_query($q,$con);
            if(!$rq)
            {
            echo " the sql query faiiled to work ";
            }
            else
            {

            }

            ?>
```

Comment: `select count(*) from question where...`

Comment: bro i not need that i need to get the  answer which will be an intger value . into a varibale . so i need the fetching part .

Comment: Read the manual: http://se2.php.net/mysql_fetch_row

Comment: @RaviSingh Then you should say that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the function `mysql_fetch_row()` to return a row from your database query as an array. You can then access the result for the `count(*)` as the first element in the returned array.

```
<?php

         $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
         $db = mysql_select_db('quiz', $con) or die(mysql_error());
         $q="count(*) from question where ans=uanswer";
         $rq=mysql_query($q,$con);
          if(!$rq)
         {
             echo " the sql query faiiled to work ";
         }
         else
         {
             $row = mysql_fetch_row($rq);
             echo $row[0];
          }

    ?>
```